# Issue with Chrome CORS policy

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, cors, axios

I have an API to login to my system, but when sending a request with axios it gets a CORS error.

[image]

I have tried to install the CORS extension and reload a lot of time, but it's still not working.

[image]

I have then tried sending requests through 
`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`, I get error 503
(Service Unavailable).

[image]

This is my function:

```
function getAccessToken (success, failure){
  axios.request({
    url: `${BaseConstants.REST_BASE_PATH}/rest/auth/login`,
    //`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${BaseConstants.REST_BASE_PATH}/rest/auth/login`,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Basic YWRtaW51c2VyOnBhc3N3b3Jk',
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      // 'Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
  }).then(r => {
    success(r.data);
  }.catch(r => { 
    failure(r.message);
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you add cors header "access-control-allow-origin "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the "cors" package as follows(express server) or can add the specific lines at the "server-side" to bypass the CORS issue.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

// some route controllers
const customRoute = require('./customRoute.controller');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


// Custom routes
app.use('/api/tags', customRoute);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));


// Catch all other routes & return index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

module.exports = app;

OR

'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': ' true'
```

Hope this solves the issue. :)